# How to concatenate with-param output and string?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have part of xml file that look like below, and I wanted to add an entry on the end.

```
                <boltPatternOnSite id="2213E0" name="3/4&quot;Ø A325" class="BoltPattern" ACADID="2213E1" setkey="1" nameBolt="A325 3/4 x 2" setBoltsType="1">
                <explicitQuantity>1</explicitQuantity>
                <set key="MuS" name="NaW"/>
                <numBolts>3</numBolts>
                <role key="Bolt#1" name="BOLT"/>
                <standard key="ASTM A325" name="A325"/>
                <diameter>19.050</diameter>
                <material key="10.9" name="10.9"/>
                <density>0.00</density>
                <boltLength>50.800</boltLength>
                <fitLength>19.863</fitLength>
                <fitLengthIncrement>0.000</fitLengthIncrement>
                <holeTolerance>1.587</holeTolerance>
                <mountLocation>0</mountLocation>
```

The output should be like this:

```
            <boltPatternOnSite id="2213E0" name="3/4&quot;Ø A325" class="BoltPattern" ACADID="2213E1" setkey="1" nameBolt="A325 3/4 x 2" setBoltsType="1">
                <explicitQuantity>1</explicitQuantity>
                <set key="MuS" name="NaW"/>
                <numBolts>3</numBolts>
                <role key="Bolt#1" name="BOLT"/>
                <standard key="ASTM A325" name="A325"/>
                <diameter>19.050</diameter>
                <material key="10.9" name="10.9"/>
                <density>0.00</density>
                <boltLength>50.800</boltLength>
                <fitLength>19.863</fitLength>
                <fitLengthIncrement>0.000</fitLengthIncrement>
                <holeTolerance>1.587</holeTolerance>
                <mountLocation>0</mountLocation>
                <UserAttribute10>3/4"Ø</UserAttribute10>
```

But I got stuck in this part of code

```
enter code here
<xsl:template match="mainpart/boltPatternOnSite" >
    <xsl:variable name="boltdia" select="./diameter" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <UserAttribute10>
            <xsl:call-template name="decimal-to-fraction">
                <xsl:with-param name="decimalnum" select="$boltdia  div 25.4" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </UserAttribute10>  
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Anyone care to point me on right track?
Here is the url of the entire code transformation and sample xml file.
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bwdwsm

Comment: You should probably use <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/> instead of the apply templates. Is that what you want to archive? You did not point out what is going wrong in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an element after others you can use this template:

```
<xsl:template match="boltPatternOnSite">
    <xsl:variable name="boltdia" select="./diameter" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@* | node()" />
        <UserAttribute10>
           <xsl:value-of select="$boltdia div 25.4"/>
        </UserAttribute10>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I managed to get the answer.

```
<xsl:template match="mainpart/boltPatternOnSite" >
    <xsl:variable name="boltdia" select="./diameter" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="result">
            <xsl:call-template name="decimal-to-fraction">
                <xsl:with-param name="decimalnum" select="$boltdia  div 25.4" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <UserAttribute10>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($result, '&quot;Ø')" />
        </UserAttribute10>  
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```